# How to end a Basic function properly

Tags: macros, libreoffice, basic, libreoffice-calc

I'm trying to write a function in Basic for LibreOffice Calc to get the first letter of each word of the selected cell using the following code:

```
Function GetFirstLetters(rng) As String
    Dim arr
    Dim I As Long
    arr = Split(rng, " ")
    If IsArray(arr) Then
        For I = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            GetFirstLetters = GetFirstLetters & Left(arr(I), 1)
        Next I
    Else
        GetFirstLetters = Left(arr, 1)
    End If
End Function
```

And it works correctly, unless I try to execute it again, then it seems that the new result gets appended to that of any previous execution and it will return both strings together, example:

[image: first example]

It also doesn't matter if I delete some or even all cells, or if I call it using an empty cell or even in another page, it will always append the result to the previous one:

[image: second example]

Why does this happen? How can I fix this behaviour?

I don't know anything about Basic, so please don't bash on me if this is something very simple.

The original function is this:

```
Function GetFirstLetters(rng As Range) As String
'Update 20140325
    Dim arr
    Dim I As Long
    arr = VBA.Split(rng, " ")
    If IsArray(arr) Then
        For I = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            GetFirstLetters = GetFirstLetters & Left(arr(I), 1)
        Next I
    Else
        GetFirstLetters = Left(arr, 1)
    End If
End Function
```

And I got it from here: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1580-excel-extract-first-letter-of-each-word.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have found is `VBA` for Excel. Openoffice or Libreoffice uses `StarBasic`, not `VBA`. This is similar but not equal. So you can't simply use the same code as in Excel.

First difference is, there is no `Range` object. This you have noticed and have used `rng` as an `Variant`.

But another difference is, function names are like variable names in the global scope. And they will not be reseted if the function is called again. So in `StarBasic` we better do:

```
Function GetFirstLetters(sCellValue as String) As String
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim I As Long
    Dim sResult As String
    arr = Split(sCellValue, " ")
    If IsArray(arr) Then
        For I = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            sResult = sResult & Left(arr(I), 1)
        Next I
    Else
        sResult = Left(arr, 1)
    End If
    GetFirstLetters = sResult
End Function
```

`sResult` is reseted (new `Dim`ed) every time the function is called. So even the function's return value.

Comment: Couldn't have figured that out by myself, thank you!